# Intellisense in Layout.cshtml for js and css not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc 5 project and did the bundles for js and css files. The problem is when I do typing jquery code in my layout.cshtml the intellisense for jquery / css is not working. Do I need to reference/import js / css on my Layout.cshtml file? But I already created the BundleConfig and it's working fine when I run the project. It's just that I can't see intellisense while typing in Layout.cshtml. Thanks for any helpful response!

Answer (score 2):

My English is not good, but I know what you mean，the bundles for js and css file will be working ，only when a page is requested。  So there is no relationship between the bundles for js and css file and intellisense。 You can try the following solution:

[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPwep.png)

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZFZm.png)

Comment: I already did that before I asked here. Question , will it affect my bundles if I explicitly imported js / css files while I have my bundles? They say that it's a bad practice to import js twice.

Comment: reference JS ： <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>    the above method is able to intellisense